# How to efficiently transfer NATIVE SOL to a program accepting WRAPPED SOL?

Tags: anchor, account, associated-token-account, transfer, sol

I am writing a program in which the accepted payment MUST be from a token account. Anchor context snippet here:

```
pub struct Payment<'info> { 
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
    ...
    ...

}
```

In order for the user to pay via SOL, i am currently doing 3 separate transactions:

1. Create WSOL account
2. Fund WSOL account with SOL
3. Call Payment with WSOL account

Although, this results in the user having to accept more than one transaction.

So I wanted to know if there are ways to do this at once, such that the user only sees SOL being deducted in the Phantom Wallet summary. I.e.  **- 1 SOL**, and not **-1 SOL, + 1 WSOL**.

I assume that I could create a transaction consisting of all 3 instructions. Would this work? If yes, are there other ways to do this as well?

Comment: what is "pure" SOL?  _Native_ SOL is the protocol base economic unit. _wrapped_ SOL is the SPL Token wrapped equivalent.  can you please update your question to clarify these terms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each transaction will require the wallet to sign the transaction.

Rather than three separate transactions, create one transaction with the three instructions. This is the only way to have the user accept only one transaction.

Something along the lines of:

```
const transaction = new web3.Transaction();

const createWsolIx = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
// some instruction
});

const fundWsolIx = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
// some instruction
});

const transferWsol = new web3.TransactionInstruction({
// some instruction
});

transaction.add(createWsolIx, fundWsolIx, transferWsol);

const tx = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, []);
```