# How to UNWRAP WSOL to SOL?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Relating to a previous question: [LINK](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/996/how-to-efficiently-transfer-native-sol-to-a-program-accepting-wrapped-sol), which covered SOL -> WSOL.

I am building an anchor program that transfers Tokens from one account to another (input and output):

```
pub struct Payment<'info> { 
    #[account(mut)]
    pub input_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
    pub output_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
    ...

}
```

Although, how would I be able to transfer WSOL from anchor-program-side to SOL user-side. That is, user can request e.g. **2 WSOL** from program and get back the equivalent **2 SOL**?

I know that you can close the WSOL account as a final instruction, but that just seems like a bad idea since you would be closing the ENTIRE WSOL account and not just the requested **2 SOL**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no other way than closing a wrapped SOL token account to recover the SOL inside it, there is no "transfer x wSOL" capability in the token program.

However, there is a trick to perform if you want to unwrap only a certain amount of wrapped SOL.

The sequence:

- Create a temporary wSOL token account
- Transfer X amount from wSOL main token account to temporary wSOL
- Close temporary wSOL token account into recipient